# Getting my React frontend to talk to my Express server

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

So I have a Digital Ocean Ubuntu VPS running Apache, Node & Mongo. I can return data from my database via CURL on the server. The node backend is definitely running on port 3000.

My React frontend uses Fetch and I currently have it pointed at localhost:3000. Is this wrong?

I'm also a little confused as to where my frontend React bundle should be on my server in relation to my server.js. Does that matter?

I can access the frontend through my domain, it just isn't grabbing the data the way it did when I worked on it locally. I must be missing something in my server.js to get them to talk to each other...

I read about Apache VirtualHost and how that might be a necessary component in running a node app on a single Apache server.. let me know if you know a thing or two about that.

Here's the httpservice.js file from the frontend:

```
var Fetch = require('whatwg-fetch');
var baseUrl = 'http://localhost:3000';

var service = {
    get: function(url) {
      return fetch(baseUrl + url)
      .then(function(response)  {
        return response.json();
      });
    },
    post: function(url, ingredient) {
      return fetch(baseUrl + url, {
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'text/plain',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        method: 'post',
        body: JSON.stringify(ingredient)
      }).then(function(response) {
        return response;
      });
    }
  };

module.exports = service;
```

And here's my server.js from the backend:

```
var express = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();

mongoose.connect('mongodb://admin:admin123@127.0.0.1:27017/food?authSource=admin');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));

var usersSchema = new Schema({
//  _id: String,
  id: String,
  vote: Number
});

var bkyes = mongoose.model('bkyes', usersSchema);

app.get('/bkyes', function(req, res) {
bkyes.find({}, function(err, bkyes) {
  res.send(bkyes);
  });
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Thanks so much for any insights, all are welcome and appreciated!!!

Comment: How does the client index.html file call all the necessary JavaScript files / libraries it needs?  It's not exactly clear on what is your question here.

Comment: It's a React frontend so the httpservice.js file just defines the GET and POST functions that get used in other irrelevant parts of the app. the index.html is just a normal index.html which calls a React bundle.js.

Comment: I'm assuming you are ONLY running this program (both client and server) on your localhost in chrome. When you inspect the code in chrome do you see any errors in the console?  Are all elements loading correctly on the network tab?  What exactly is your question here?

Comment: No everything is on a DigitalOcean VPS. When I change `var baseUrl = 'http://localhost:3000';` to `var baseUrl = 'http://MY_SERVER_IP:3000';` It still doesn't find anything. I will change my question to indicate this server is a VPS not running locally. My question is what am I missing. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I chose a preconfigured Digital Ocean server with a basic firewall installed. Since my app is running on port 3000 it was blocking the GET and POST requests. I fixed it by running this on my server:

```
sudo ufw allow 3000
```

Also in my httpservice.js file I changed `var baseUrl = 'http://localhost:3000';` to:

```
var baseUrl = 'http://MY_SERVER_IP:3000';
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your server on your local machine ? Otherwise, I think you should put the domain name or its IP address in `baseURL`.
In fact, when you access your frontend, the js script generated from React is executed by your browser, on your local machine. So it tries to access the port 3000 on your computer. But your node backend is still on your server.

Comment: Yeah I tried that, it didn't seem to help. I will probably investigate that again though, thank you.

Comment: Don't hesitate to open the web inspector and to look at the network tab, in order to see what page isn't loaded and why. Express also generate logs in a file which sould be located at `/home/username/.forever/randomcharacters.log`.

Comment: Well, that's wrong. I have these logs because I use the forever deamon. My bad.

Comment: No that is good advice, looking at the network tab I see that `Fetch` has failed in my GET and POST requests. Looking at my node_modules folder on my server now and it looks like the Fetch module may have failed during installation or something; i'm not seeing it. Thanks, I will report back.

Comment: No it was there... still on the hunt